# Tensorflow Matrix square Root code source

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

Where can we get the source code of the tf.linalg.sqrtm and can we modify it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tf.linalg.sqrtm` is just an alias for `matrix_square_root`. The source for which is hosted on github and can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/df3a3375941b9e920667acfe72fb4c33a8f45503/tensorflow/contrib/opt/python/training/matrix_functions.py).

TensorFlow code is open source under the Apache Licence so, sure, if you know what you are doing you can fork it and amend it to your own requirements. Maybe if your use-case is specific to your own requirements you could also just build your own alternative `sqrtm` function.

Answer (score 0):

Another option for computing square root is to approximate it with an iterative solution like [Denmann-Beavers iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix#By_Denman%E2%80%93Beavers_iteration).  I had to do this when implementing a model in `tflite`, on which `tf.linalg.sqrtm()` is not supported (unless you go through the hassle of adding custom ops)

```
def tf_denmann_beavers_sqrtm(matrix: TensorInvCovMat, n_iter=10):
    """
    Approximate the matrix-square-root by Denmann Beavers iteration
        https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix#By_Denman%E2%80%93Beavers_iteration
    Convergence is not guaranteed.  Use at your own risk!
    """
    ym = matrix
    zm = tf.eye(tf.shape(matrix[0])[0], dtype=matrix.dtype)
    for i in range(n_iter):
        ym_ = 0.5 * (ym + tf.linalg.inv(zm))
        zm = 0.5 * (zm + tf.linalg.inv(ym))
        ym = ym_
    return ym
```

```
def test_tf_denmann_beavers_sqrtm():
    invcov_matrix = tf.constant([
        [4496.2685546875, -384.8538513183594, -3997.38623046875],
        [-384.8897705078125, 8825.5615234375, -8400.1064453125],
        [-3997.349853515625, -8400.1416015625, 12311.6171875]
    ], dtype=tf.float32)
    mat_sqrt = tf.linalg.sqrtm(invcov_matrix).numpy()
    approx_mat_sqrt = tf_denmann_beavers_sqrtm(invcov_matrix, n_iter=10).numpy()
    assert np.allclose(mat_sqrt, approx_mat_sqrt, atol=1e-3)
```